# iPhone App rejection under guideline 2.16

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

This is the second time my app was rejected due the GPS background key. Here is the code I am using:

```
-(void)stopGPS{
[self.locationManagerAll stopUpdatingLocation];
self.locationManagerAll.delegate = nil;
locationManagerAll = nil;
self.cloop = 1;

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"UpdateLocation"];
[prefs setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"updationTime"];
[prefs synchronize];
[set.gpsOnOff setOn:NO];
[set.settingsTable reloadData];
[self stopThread];
}
-(void)startGPS{

if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
    if(self.locationManagerAll == nil){
        self.locationManagerAll = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManagerAll.delegate = self;
    }
    self.locationManagerAll.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    self.locationManagerAll.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [self.locationManagerAll startUpdatingLocation];

}else {
    [set.gpsOnOff setOn:NO];
    [set.settingsTable reloadData];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Service Disabled" 
                                                    message:@"To re-enable, please go to   Settings and turn on Location Service for this app." 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release]; 
}
}
```

These above functions used to start or stop the GPS location, Here are the implementations for GPS location:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([oldLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow] < - 5) return;
if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 5.0) return;
if (newLocation.coordinate.latitude == oldLocation.coordinate.latitude && newLocation.coordinate.longitude == oldLocation.coordinate.longitude) return;
NSString *currentLatitude = [[NSString alloc] 
                             initWithFormat:@"%f", 
                             newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *currentLongitude = [[NSString alloc] 
                              initWithFormat:@"%f",
                              newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
[prefs setValue:currentLatitude forKey:@"UpdateLocationLati"];
[prefs setValue:currentLongitude forKey:@"UpdateLocationLongi"];
[prefs synchronize];
[currentLatitude release];
[currentLongitude release];
if (self.cloop == 1) {
    /*UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Current location saved." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];
     [alert release]; */

    self.cloop = 0;
    [prefs setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:60] forKey:@"updationTime"];
    [prefs setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"UpdateLocation"];
    [prefs synchronize];
    [set.gpsOnOff setOn:YES];
    [set.settingsTable reloadData];
    [self startThread];
}
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
if ([error code] != kCLErrorLocationUnknown) {
    [self stopGPS];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setTitle:@"Location"];
    [alert setMessage:@"Unable to get current location"];
    [alert setDelegate:self.set];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Retry"];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
}
```

I am also using a thread for timer which update the location on server after every second. AS the timer stop when the app went to background I am using this code to handle this:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
/*
 Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
 If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.*/
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) { //Check if our iOS version supports multitasking I.E iOS 4
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) { //Check if device supports mulitasking
        UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; //Get the shared application instance


        __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task; //Create a task object
        background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
            [application endBackgroundTask:background_task]; 
            //Tell the system that we are done with the tasks
            background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Set the task to be invalid
            //System will be shutting down the app at any point in time now
        }];
        //Background tasks require you to use asyncrous tasks
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            //Perform your tasks that your application requires                
            //I do what i need to do here.... synchronously...                
            NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"updationTime"] intValue] > 0 && [[prefs objectForKey:@"UpdateLocation"] boolValue]) {
                self.backgroundTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:[[prefs objectForKey:@"updationTime"] intValue] target:self selector:@selector(backgroundTriggerTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
                NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
                [runLoop addTimer:backgroundTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
                [runLoop run];
            }
            [application endBackgroundTask:background_task]; 
            //End the task so the system knows that you are done with what you need to perform
            background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Invalidate the background_task
        });
    }else if (![[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"UpdateLocation"] boolValue]){
            [self stopGPS];
        }
    }
}else if (![[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"UpdateLocation"] boolValue]){
        [self stopGPS];
    }
}
}
```

Here is the thread code I am using:

```
-(void)startThread
{
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"UpdateLocation"] boolValue]) {
    self.updateLocation = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setUpTimerThread) object:nil];
    [self.updateLocation start];
}
}
-(void)stopThread{
[self.updateLocation cancel];
updateLocation = nil;
[self.gpsTimer invalidate];
}
-(void)setUpTimerThread
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"updationTime"] intValue] > 0) {
    self.gpsTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:[[prefs objectForKey:@"updationTime"] intValue] target:self selector:@selector(triggerTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runLoop addTimer:gpsTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [runLoop run];
}
[pool release];
}
-(void)triggerTimer
{
NSLog(@"***Timer Called after seconds**");
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *location = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f_%f",[[prefs objectForKey:@"UpdateLocationLati"] doubleValue], [[prefs objectForKey:@"UpdateLocationLongi"] doubleValue]] autorelease];
NSString *urlGen = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%d/%@",[prefs objectForKey:@"update_user_location"],[[prefs objectForKey:@"USERID"] intValue], location] autorelease];
NSLog(@"urlGen: %@", urlGen);
NSString *rt = [JSONModel stringWithUrl:urlGen];
if (self.alertLoop == 1) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"GPS location has been sent. This alert message will only prompt you once." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    self.alertLoop = 0;
}
NSLog(@"UPDATE LOCATION : %d", [rt intValue]);
}
```

I am totally confused. I dont know if I miss something. Can any body please help me out.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't look like you missed something but one of the possible reasons for 2.16 rejection is the absence of GPS battery warning in your app description on the app meta in iTunesConnect - "The continued use of GPS may decrease battery life" or something like that.

Comment: I have the same problem, and that description was the solution

Comment: I'd added this note in the disclaimer when the app starts. Do I must need to add it in app meta in iTunesConnect?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely have to include it in the app meta in iTunesConnect. You don't have to reupload the binary though, if your app doesn't have code-level problems, just fix the meta then send them a message in Resolution Center in iTC.

Comment: I'd submitted app with battery disclaimer in meta but apple rejected the app again. I posted them about the disclaimer message but they response me this: "Since you do not have any persistent location features running in the background, it would be appropriate to remove location background mode from your plist.info. Simply adding the disclaimer does not resolve the issue." can any body explain how can I achieve persistent location?

Comment: Do you actually use location services when your app is running in background? If not, you should probably remove the "location" key from `UIBackgroundModes` in your info.plist file. If you do, then make sure location manager doesn't stop when app is going into background.

Comment: As my code above describe I am clearly using location services when my app is running in background. As my business idea is to ask user if he wants to send his/her location after every minute, if he he/she said yes, we initiated location services and timer thread as my code above describe. This process will then help us find out where the specific user is so that his/her community can find him/her if he's around. I've double checked it didn't stop when app is in background.

Comment: I think you should send them a message explaining how exactly your background location services work. I had the same problem with app rejection couple of months ago - battery disclaimer and background location services - so I had to explain my background mechanics to review team.